# Columns visualization in Bootstrap layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't visualise two column in a row. Do you know why?
I make the container, the row and then two `columns-md-4` each with `<h3>`, `<p>` and a `<table>`. When I load the page on browser I can't see it well formatted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Random App </title>
     <meta name="description" content="Random App">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>

<style>
body{
padding-top: 40px
}
</style>

<body>

    <!--Navbar-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Random</a>

          </div> <!--Navbar Header-->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <li><a href="#feed">Feed</a>
               <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
               <li><a href="#feature">Feature</a>
               <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
             </ul>  
        </div> <!--End container-->
    </nav>  <!--End nav-->


             <!--jumbotron-->
        <div class="jumbotron">
         <div class="container text-center">
          <h1>Jumbotron</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean auctor, erat quis suscipit auctor, justo lacus eleifend</p>
             </div><!--End Container-->
        </div><!--End jumbotron-->

        <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3>Table A</h3>
               <p> Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
             <blockquote>
             <footer>ujuyj</footer>
             </blockquote>
             <table class="table table-hover">
              <thead>
                <tr class="success">
                 <th>Name</th>
                 <th>Website</th>
                 <th>By</th>
                </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                 <tr>
                     <td>UnoCento</td>  
                     <td>www.example.test</td>
                     <td>TreCento</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td>UnoCento</td>  
                     <td>www.example.test</td>
                     <td>TreCento</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td>UnoCento</td>  
                     <td>www.example.test</td>
                     <td>TreCento</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td>UnoCento</td>  
                     <td>www.example.test</td>
                     <td>TreCento</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td>UnoCento</td>  
                     <td>www.example.test</td>
                     <td>TreCento</td>
                 </tr>
                </tbody>

                </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>Table B</h3>
         <p> Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
         <blockquote>
       <footer>ujuyj</footer>
       </blockquote>
       <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr class="success">
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Website</th>
         <th>By</th>
        </tr>
         </thead>
               <tbody>
                 <tr>
                     <td>UnoCento</td>  
                     <td>www.example.test</td>
                     <td>TreCento</td>
                 </tr>
         <tr>
                     <td>UnoCento</td>  
                     <td>www.example.test</td>
                     <td>TreCento</td>
                 </tr>
         <tr>
                     <td>UnoCento</td>  
                     <td>www.example.test</td>
                     <td>TreCento</td>
                 </tr>
         <tr>
                     <td>UnoCento</td>  
                     <td>www.example.test</td>
                     <td>TreCento</td>
                 </tr>
         <tr>
                     <td>UnoCento</td>  
                     <td>www.example.test</td>
                     <td>TreCento</td>
                 </tr>
                </tbody>

            </div>




          </div><!--End Row-->
        </div><!--End Container>        



    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Tons of missing closing tags

You didn't properly closed your  tags. Both `<div>`s with the `col-md-4` classes were missing a closing  tag right after your `</tbody>` tag.

You also miss a closing `</div>` for your `<div class="container">` in your `<nav>`, not to mention that all of your `<li>`s miss their closing `</li>`s in your Navbar Header code block.

### What you should have done

You would have noticed this if you had had proper indentation or had used an IDE with start-end tag highlighting.

Cmon, even Stack Overflow's snippet tool would give a warning, if you had taken the effort to create a snippet and press the tidy button.

See the red closing tag? That means you have an error:

[image: Errors marked with red in your code.]

This is not how a list should look like after a tidy:

[image: Ugly list]

### The proper code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Random App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Random App">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>

<style>
  body {
    padding-top: 40px
  }
</style>

<body>

  <!--Navbar-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Random</a>

      </div>
      <!--Navbar Header-->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#feed">Feed</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#feature">Feature</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
      <!--End container-->
  </nav>
  <!--End nav-->


  <!--jumbotron-->
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <h1>Jumbotron</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean auctor, erat quis suscipit auctor, justo lacus eleifend</p>
    </div>
    <!--End Container-->
  </div>
  <!--End jumbotron-->

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>Table A</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
        <blockquote>
          <footer>ujuyj</footer>
        </blockquote>
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr class="success">
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Website</th>
              <th>By</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>UnoCento</td>
              <td>www.example.test</td>
              <td>TreCento</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>UnoCento</td>
              <td>www.example.test</td>
              <td>TreCento</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>UnoCento</td>
              <td>www.example.test</td>
              <td>TreCento</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>UnoCento</td>
              <td>www.example.test</td>
              <td>TreCento</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>UnoCento</td>
              <td>www.example.test</td>
              <td>TreCento</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>Table B</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
        <blockquote>
          <footer>ujuyj</footer>
        </blockquote>
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr class="success">
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Website</th>
              <th>By</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>UnoCento</td>
              <td>www.example.test</td>
              <td>TreCento</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>UnoCento</td>
              <td>www.example.test</td>
              <td>TreCento</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>UnoCento</td>
              <td>www.example.test</td>
              <td>TreCento</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>UnoCento</td>
              <td>www.example.test</td>
              <td>TreCento</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>UnoCento</td>
              <td>www.example.test</td>
              <td>TreCento</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>




    </div>
    <!--End Row-->
  </div>
  <!--End Container>        



    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. After each </tbody> there is a </div>. It is closing col-md-4.
Is it wrong?

Comment: @DisplayEman Yes, but you need a `</table>` between the `</tbody>` and the `</div>`. Also check out my other findings in my updated answer.

Comment: @toymedli Thank you. Didn't close the </table> between </tbody> and columns </div>

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/33/

**HTML**

```
    <!--Navbar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Random</a>

        </div> <!--Navbar Header-->

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#feed">Feed</a>
                    <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
                        <li><a href="#feature">Feature</a>
                            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                            </ul>  
                        </div> <!--End container-->
                    </nav>  <!--End nav-->


                    <!--jumbotron-->
                    <div class="jumbotron">
                        <div class="container text-center">
                            <h1>Jumbotron</h1>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean auctor, erat quis suscipit auctor, justo lacus eleifend</p>
                        </div><!--End Container-->
                    </div><!--End jumbotron-->


                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <h3>Table A</h3>
                            <p> Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
                            <blockquote>
                                <footer>ujuyj</footer>
                            </blockquote>
                            <table class="table table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr class="success">
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Website</th>
                                        <th>By</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>UnoCento</td>  
                                        <td>www.example.test</td>
                                        <td>TreCento</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>UnoCento</td>  
                                        <td>www.example.test</td>
                                        <td>TreCento</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>UnoCento</td>  
                                        <td>www.example.test</td>
                                        <td>TreCento</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>UnoCento</td>  
                                        <td>www.example.test</td>
                                        <td>TreCento</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>UnoCento</td>  
                                        <td>www.example.test</td>
                                        <td>TreCento</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <h3>Table B</h3>
                            <p> Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
                            <blockquote>
                                <footer>ujuyj</footer>
                            </blockquote>
                            <table class="table table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr class="success">
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Website</th>
                                        <th>By</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>UnoCento</td>  
                                        <td>www.example.test</td>
                                        <td>TreCento</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>UnoCento</td>  
                                        <td>www.example.test</td>
                                        <td>TreCento</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>UnoCento</td>  
                                        <td>www.example.test</td>
                                        <td>TreCento</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>UnoCento</td>  
                                        <td>www.example.test</td>
                                        <td>TreCento</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>UnoCento</td>  
                                        <td>www.example.test</td>
                                        <td>TreCento</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>

                    </div><!--End Row-->


                </div>
```